# Get all Item by a Foregin key of Vendor in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I wanna display all items owned by a vendor and display under the vendor page. Like doordash/ubereats.

Please refer me to any link that can resolve this issue, Also I can spend time on learning database if there is any for this kind of setup.

**models.py**

```
class Vendor(models.Model):


    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cover = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, 
    upload_to=upload_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
 ("Alcohol", "Alcohol"),
 ("Food", "Food"),
 ("Snacks", "Snacks"),

   ]

class Item(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, related_name='vendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=None, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=upload_path)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='store_owner', null=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class ItemVenderView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    queryset = Item.objects.all()


def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    #Can do this way but I don't wanna do this way,there should be more eligant way, 
    # here I have to serialize queryset
    
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    test_suite_qs = Item.objects.filter(vendor=pk)
    print(test_suite_qs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Todo
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'completed', 'cover')


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ("id", 'slug', "title", "price", "category", "quantity", "picture",'vendor')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'todos', views.TodoView, 'todo')
router.register(r'get-store', views.ItemVenderView, 'get-store')
router.register(r'item', views.ItemView, 'item')
router.register(r'cart', views.AddToCartView, 'cart')
router.register(r'payments', views.AddToCartView, 'payments')
router.register(r'delete-item', views.OrderItemDeleteView, 'delete-item')
router.register(r'order-item', views.OrderQuantityUpdateView, 'order-item')

urlpatterns = [

    path('todo/', include(router.urls)),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('', views.home),
    # path('delete-item/<pk>/', views.OrderItemDeleteView, name="delete-item")
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am sending **PK** on url itself.

Comment: kindly share your `urls.py`

Comment: @Jimmar Thanks Jimmar for your reply. I have added urls.py in the question itself.